# Where is the compiled java code stored in an nsf / ntf?

Tags: xpages

Where is the compiled java code stored in an nsf / ntf?   Or is it compiled from the java "files" at runtime?

I looked all through the java perspective but do not see anything that jumps out at me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under **WebContent/WEB-INF/classes**. You can find it with **Navigator** (Window -> Show Eclipse Views -> Navigator).