# Class files not being created after refresh from template?

Tags: xpages

Thanks to Panu

[Where is the compiled java code stored in an nsf / ntf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701085/where-is-the-compiled-java-code-stored-in-an-nsf-ntf)

I was able to see where class files get created in the nsf.   I am having an issue with some java classes that I created (.java files) where the class files (.class files) are not being created after template refresh.

1. If I do a clean / build in the nsf then it fixes the issue.
2. If I first delete the java files out of the nsf then it fixes the issue for the moment.
3. If I create a brand new db from the template then it works for the moment.

If I get the issue fixed then I can see the class files in the nsf.  As soon as I refresh from template, the class files are removed in the nsf and never created.

Any idea what is wrong?

P.S. The class files are being created in the ntf.

Comment: What happens when you refresh the design after a change. Did the onetime fix (new db/manual delete) fix it? Can you repeat the issue with new templates/dbs and are you on ODS51? If repeatable it's PMR time

Comment: for situations like this we have adopted standard: special view showing design elements, where you can check some special attributes of all design elements, especially $Flags containing "P" and $Class.

Comment: @Steve - After I fix the issue (no matter how) and I refresh the class files go away.  I did create a new db as mentioned in my post above, the first time the db is created, the class files are there but as soon as I refresh they are gone.  I am running Revision 20110916.0921 (Release 8.5.3) of the designer.   I will test if I can repeat with a new template.

Comment: @Franrisek - I really don't know what you are trying to say.  How do you create this view?

Comment: @BruceStemplewski http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/view-of-design-elements.htm that way you can see the cause of some problems with design refresh/replace

Comment: I have been able to duplicate the issue with a brand new ntf and nsf.

Comment: Is this a custom template? Or an existing template form the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started a PMR with IBM and they were able to reproduce the issue in 8.5.3 but not 9.0

Comment: Having this problem, too. Blogged about my case: http://lostinxpages.com/2013/08/20/puzzling-behaviour-of-java-class-files-in-design-refreshes-in-xpages/